# How to use SpEL in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have declare bean like these:

```
<bean id="kenny"
    class="com.springinaction.springidol.Instrumentalist">
    <property name="song" value="Price Tag"></property> 
    <property name="age" value="27"></property> 
    <property name="instrument">
        <bean class="com.springinaction.springidol.Saxophone"/>
    </property> 
</bean>

<bean id="carl"
  class="com.springinaction.springidol.Instrumentalist">
    <property name="song" value="#{kenny.song}" />
    <property name="instrument">
        <bean class="com.springinaction.springidol.Saxophone"/>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Why the song property of carl is  "#{kenny.song}" not "Price Tag"?
What am I missing to use SpEL in Spring?

Comment: Your above config works for me using Spring 3.2.6. What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: SpEL was introduced in Spring 3. You'll need to upgrade your Spring libraries in order to make use of it.